# Using cell value as SOQL field with G-connector

Tags: soql

Is there a way to call for a cell value when building the SOQL query using G-connector for Google Sheets or Excel?

E.g.

SELECT A FROM B WHERE C= ''Sheet Name'!C5'

Kindly,
Rasmus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is! :)

SELECT A FROM B WHERE C= '[Sheet Name!C5]'

Comment: I can't get this to work, has it changed?
select Account.Id, Account.Name, Account.Phone from Account where Name = '[TEST!A1]' limit 10000
But this works fine.
select Account.Id, Account.Name, Account.Phone from Account where  Name = 'Joy Hanawa' limit 10000