# Using cell value as SOQL query with G-Connector for Salesforce

Tags: google-sheets, salesforce, soql

Is there a way to store SOQL queries in a table and get data exported to different sheets (1 SOQL query = 1 sheet)?

[Using Custom Formulas to Dynamically Pull Data From Salesforce](https://www.xappex.com/knowledge-base/using-custom-formulas-to-dynamically-pull-data-from-salesforce-2/) doesn't work for me because I need the output to be a table with field grouping (like a pivot table).
[Using cell value as SOQL field with G-connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45057561/using-cell-value-as-soql-field-with-g-connector#new-answer?newreg=62be20aab8914b338b4ef14e713c7c12) doesn't work for me because I need some field names to be stored in cells, not field values.

Thanks!